# Split string by all spaces except those in parentheses

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

I'm trying to split text the following like on spaces:

```
var line = "Text (what is)|what's a story|fable called|named|about {Search}|{Title}"
```

but I want it to ignore the spaces within parentheses. This should produce an array with:

```
var words = ["Text", "(what is)|what's", "a", "story|fable" "called|named|about", "{Search}|{Title}"];
```

I know this should involve some sort of regex with line.match(). Bonus points if the regex removes the parentheses. I know that word.replace() would get rid of them in a subsequent step.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the following approach with specific regex pattern(based on *negative lookahead assertion*):

```js
var line = "Text (what is)|what's a story|fable called|named|about {Search}|{Title}",
    words = line.split(/(?!\(.*)\s(?![^(]*?\))/g);
  
console.log(words);
```

- `(?!\(.*)` ensures that a separator `\s` is not preceded by brace `(`(including attendant characters)
- `(?![^(]*?\))` ensures that a separator `\s` is not followed by brace `)`(including attendant characters)

Comment: Can you give a example as to why you couldn't simply use `\s(?![^(]*?\))`

Comment: Definitely doesn't seem like the first group does anything: https://regex101.com/r/l49ycn/4

Answer (score 0):

Not a single regexp but does the job. Removes the parentheses and splits the text by spaces.

```
var words = line.replace(/[\(\)]/g,'').split(" ");
```

Comment: But he doesn't want to remove the parentheses.

Comment: At the end of the question there's "Bonus points if the regex removes the parentheses." So I think it's an optional feature for him.

Comment: You're right. But won't your regexp split on the spaces inside the parentheses? By the way, those escapes inside the character set are not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

One approach which is useful in some cases is to replace spaces inside parens with a placeholder, then split, then unreplace:

```js
var line = "Text (what is)|what's a story|fable called|named|about {Search}|{Title}";

var result = line.replace(/\((.*?)\)/g, m => m.replace(' ', 'SPACE'))
  .split(' ')
  .map(x => x.replace(/SPACE/g, ' '));
  
console.log(result);
```