# JavaScript split by space ignoring parentheses

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to split a string by space but ignore those in parentheses, or after an opening parenthesis. I followed [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41075573/split-string-by-all-spaces-except-those-in-parentheses) but my case is a little bit more complicated. For example if the parentheses are balanced, that solution works fine:

```js
// original string
let string = 'attribute1 in (a, b, c) attribute2 in (d, e)';
words = string.split(/(?!\(.*)\s(?![^(]*?\))/g);
console.log(words)
```

expected result after split:

```js
words = ['attribute1', 'in', '(a, b, c)', 'attribute2', 'in', '(d, e)']
```

However if the parentheses are not balanced, let's say:

```js
// original string
let string = 'attribute1 in (a, b, c) attribute2 in (d, e';
```

Then the result I expected should be:

```js
['attribute1', 'in', '(a, b, c)', 'attribute2', 'in', '(d, e']
```

instead of

```js
['attribute1', 'in', '(a, b, c)', 'attribute2', 'in', '(d,', 'e']
```

How should I achieve this?

Comment: Are the missing parentheses consistent? Could you do a pre-step to add the parentheses back in before the split?

Comment: The missing parenthesis is the real case. Basically a user will type in this string into a search box on the frontend and it will split this string dynamically as the input changes.

Comment: Can you include the splitting code in the question itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can balance the string out by adding the missing parentheses at the end.

Note that a situation like

`"attribute1 in (a, b, c attribute2 in (d, e"`

would result in

`[ 'attribute1', 'in', '(a,', 'b,', 'c', 'attribute2', 'in', '(d, e' ]`

and the solution assumes this is the expected outcome.

If yes - here's the solution:

```js
/**
 * @param {string} s
 * @returns {string[]}
 */
function split(s) {
  let unclosed_count = 0;

  // count unclosed parentheses
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if (s[i] == '(') {
      unclosed_count++;
    } else if (s[i] == ')') {
      unclosed_count--;
    }
  }

  // close off the parentheses
  for (let i = 0; i < unclosed_count; i++) {
    s += ')';
  }

  // split
  let words = s.split(/(?!\(.*)\s(?![^(]*?\))/g);

  // remove the added parentheses from the last item
  let li = words.length - 1;
  words[li] = words[li].slice(0, -unclosed_count);

  return words;
}

let string = 'attribute1 in (a, b, c) attribute2 in (d, e';
let words = split(string);

console.log(words);
// => [ 'attribute1', 'in', '(a, b, c)', 'attribute2', 'in', '(d, e' ]
```

cheers!

---

also worth considering a case where instead of the opening brackets `(` being unmatched, there would exist some closing brackets `)` that are unmatched aswell.

i.e. `"attribute1 in a, b, c) attribute2 in d, e)"`

this was not mentioned in the problem so it's not inside the solution either, but in case this matters, you'd want to do the same thing we did with `unclosed_count`, but reverse, with i.e. `unopened_count`.